# Extraction - only numbers from address

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, clipboard, imacros

The address of Japan is written in many sites as `〒000 - 0000`.
From this, I would like to extract only numbers using imacros.
In other words, I want to remove `〒` and `-`.
I want to copy the extracted data, save it on the clipboard and paste it in another place.
Thank you.

(chrome 70.0.3538.102, Win10_x64)

Comment: @Strawberryshrub, I don't "agree" with the Edits to format the different parts that were between Double Quotes... For iMacros it is very important to "see" leading/trailing Spaces in an Extract as it "dictates" the exact Syntax that will be used in the 'EVAL()' Statement for the final Result. (Reason as well why I used '_' as Delimiters in my Answer to display in the 'PROMPT'...)  The Forum Formatting is not very "clear" about such Spaces, and by editing the Post, you introduce a "Risk" that you might have added/removed such Spaces, or even the Formatting itself...

Comment: I see the problem and you are right. I didnt find an option to withdraw the edit or even flag it? What can I do to take back the edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as a separate Solution, as the Input from the Extract is now "a bit" different and changes the Syntax in 'EVAL()' quite a bit, even if I tried to reuse a bit the same Syntax with the same Commands like in Answer_#1. (And that gives a 2nd Code Example...)

```
SET !EXTRACT  "〒 000-0000"
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var x,y,z; x=s.substr(2); y=x.split('-'); z=y[0]+y[1]; z;")
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!VAR1}}
PROMPT EXTRACT:<SP>_{{!EXTRACT}}_<BR>Numbers:<SP>_{{!VAR1}}_
```

(Tested on iMacros for FF v8.8.2, Pale Moon v26.3.3 (=FF47), Win10_x64.)

And again, there would be more than 10 different ways to implement the same Functionality to get the same Result...

Comment: Thank you very much! It's be solved. It needs knowledge of regular expressions to master EVAL? I would like to write smoothly like you. I am using v 10.0.5 for CR (free). thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Oh, good, Thanks for accepting the Answer, really boosting my "Reputation", ah-ah...! +15 Pts, oh-oh...!  Well about "regular expressions", yeah, that helps indeed, but it is not "required", I am an Advanced User and I never use REGEX that I find too complicated, I always find a different way to implement the same Functionality without REGEX, usually with 'split()' which can be very powerful...

Answer (score 0):

"Nice" to select the 'Chrome' + 'Firefox' Forum Tags but more useful would be if you had mentioned your FCI for both Browsers..., but the following Implementation for example should work in both Browsers for all iMacros Versions:

```
SET !EXTRACT  "〒000 - 0000"
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var x,y,z; x=s.substr(1); y=x.split(' '); z=y[0]+y[2]; z;")
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!VAR1}}
PROMPT EXTRACT:<SP>_{{!EXTRACT}}_<BR>Numbers:<SP>_{{!VAR1}}_
```

(Tested on iMacros for FF v8.8.2, Pale Moon v26.3.3 (=FF47), Win10_x64.)

"for example" => as you could implement the Functionality that you want in more than 10 ways using all kinds of different Combinations with other JS String Methods...

(I didn't include the Content of '{{!CLIPBOARD}}' in the 'PROMPT' as this is not supported on CR, but a 'Paste' from your OS Clipboard in 'Notepad' for example should still work...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
It worked well.
However, the data I acquired is "〒 000-0000" and "
There was a half-width space between 〒 "and" 000-0000 "(I overlooked this ...) Therefore, the error notation" undefined "was made.Please tell me once again. Thank you.

Comment: Ah...!, this is indeed for iMacros a "completely different" Input, the 'EVAL()' is always exactly "tailored" on what Input/Format you expect from the Extract...  => OK, posting the adapted Script as a separate Answer, you can each time see in the 'SET !EXTRACT' part which Input I started from, and that gives you 2 different Sample Codes...

Comment: Oh, and you've mentioned (part of) your FCI, but the most important Info is still missing... => The iMacros Version...! Will probably be v10.0.5 for CR I reckon...?, => 'Free' or 'PE'...? (Well I used '!VAR1' deliberately to make the Script work also in the 'Free' Version...)